# Ternary operator returns false but execute left side?

Tags: php

I have this row:

```
<input type="text" name="mpsRegnomer" er="невалиден номер" id="mpsRegnomer" class="upertrim inputGSmall" value="' . (isset($this->data['mpsRegnomer'])) ? '2' : '3' . '" style="margin-top:0px"/>
```

And it returns me `2` for value, when I use this row above it:

```
var_dump(isset($this->data['mpsRegnomer'])); exit;
```

It returns me `bool(false)` ? Based on documentation it should return me `3` instead of `2` ?

Comment: Operator precedence (ternary expression is run after concatenating the string). This is the wrong place to make your code terse (= less readable).

Comment: @u_mulder It's not duplicate, there is nothing with `isset vs empty vs is_null` it returns false and it execute left part, I'm ok with `isset` part :)

Comment: @mario You are right, if i export logic in variable it works fine :)

Comment: If that's some mapping logic you need for multiple forms/inputs, perhaps wrap it in some custom function.